# Getting virtual IP address of thin client in Javascript

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Don't know whether it is doable.

We are currently using terminal server and thin clients in our network and planning to get each of its virtual IP addresses using Javascript to handle an application that runs on each thin clients.

It is currently now returning all the virtual IPs that are assigned for each thin clients. Is there any way that I can get only the assigned virtual IP address for one particular thin client? Below is the code which returns all virtual IP address

Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Thanks in advance

Comment: JS doesn't have access to a client's IP address...

Comment: @Cerbrus I have managed to take the IP address using webrtc. but it returns all IP address of thin clients connected to terminal server

Comment: perhaps if you show the code that gives you "all the virtual IPs" we can help you expand on your method

Comment: @andrew please see the question now

Comment: "to run handle an application that runs"?

Comment: @AaronDigulla thats a typo :)

Answer (score 1):

Your application is running on the server, not the thin client. That's the whole idea of the thin client: It's a display + keyboard without its own CPU.

So when you run an application and you ask for "what is my IP address", then you get the server's address back because that is the place where you application is really running. The server simulates a graphics card so the app can render and then sends snapshots of this image to your thin client.

Now if you told us what kind of hardward and software you're using (terminal server, thin client, etc) then there might be a special option.

Or look into the documentation of your terminal server. Somehow, it maps a user login to a terminal. That's probably the way to go to identify a terminal (you probably don't want to show everyone the same app, you want to show each user his/her app).